# How to make a custom php output in drupal and fix it on a specific relative path?

Tags: drupal, module

I am trying to make a module which generates output at a specific relative path say mysite.com/newcomment/

What I am trying to do: 
On client side I have coded JS which makes ajax request to "mysite.com/newcomment/". If there is any new comment, on "mysite.com/newcomment/" output " have done comment on " is generated and same is shown on client side in a pop-up.

What I have done previously:
If I am making a page/article, header and footer code is coming with output.
I have also made a endpoint for it via web service but i don't want that-much complexity.

Am I doing it the right way any pointers or clues will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very confusing but from the title it sounds like your looking for hook_menu

Check out: [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

Your custom url will be created with code that looks like:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['example/feed'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example RSS feed', 
    'page callback' => 'my_module_page', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Then output the code on the page callback:

```
my_module_page {
  return '<h2 class=test>Hello World</h2>';
}
```

While you normally want html to be generated using theme functions for better caching this should at least get you started.

Edit:

To print only the data such as in an ajax call the function should look like this. Of course only include the code for your version of Drupal:

```
my_module_page {
  // Drupal 7
  print 'string'; 
  drupal_exit();;

  // Drupal 6
  print 'string'; 
  module_invoke_all('exit'); 
  exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i am  looking for solution which doesn't include code of  -header- and -footer- but directly just outputs
"<h2 class=test>Hello World</h2>" and not a single other HTML element.

Comment: Change "return" in the second snippet with "print" and you will see it as you need.

Comment: Right so like Ayesh said instead of return do "print 'string'; drupal_exit();" for drupal 7. For drupal 6 do "print 'string'; module_invoke_all('exit'); exit;"